# Generate all connected non-isomorphic graphs of n vertices modulo local complementation?

Tags: graph-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, mathematical-software

I'd like to generate a list of all simple, connected, undirected graphs of $n$ vertices, modulo standard graph isomorphism, **and modulo local complementation**, which is the following operation: for a graph $G=(V,E)$, mark a vertex $v\in V$, and let $S_v$ be its neighbourhood (such that $v\not\in S_v$). Let $C_v$ be a complete graph on the vertices $S_v$. Then define $G'=G\ \mathrm{xor}\ C_v$, i.e. for any pair of vertices in the neighbourhood of $v$, we negate the existence of an edge.

An example of this operation can be seen in fig. 1 in [arXiv:0710.2243](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2243.pdf).

For **edge local complementation**, there seems to be a way to enumerate all such graphs efficiently, see the number sequence on https://oeis.org/A156800.

I know of the program `geng`, which gives me all non-isomorphic graphs of $n$ vertices. Currently I use it with Mathematica together with a custom comparator that, given a graph $G_1$, checks whether it is isomorph to any of all possible local complements of $G_2$; unfortunately that is slow due to the extensive use of `IsomorphicGraphQ`, and because there is a lot of local complements to any given graph.

Does anyone know of a more efficient way of generating said graphs? Maybe directly using something within `nauty`?

Thanks a lot!
- JB

Comment: This sounds difficult.  One thing you are probably doing already: make a cheap invariant (eg sum of the squares of the degrees) and only use an isomorphism test if the invariants match.

Comment: That's already an excellent idea. That sped it up by a factor of 10.

Comment: Which makes me wonder if Mathematica doesn't do this by default in `IsomorphicGraphQ`.

There is in fact an efficient way of _recognizing_ LC-equivalence, in 10.1007/BF01275668. But if there's an efficient enumeration instead of removing duplicates I'd be happier.

Thanks!

Comment: It is an excellent problem.  Is this true: if $G$ and $H$ are LC-isomorphic (equivalent by LC and isomorphism), then there are vertices $u$ of $G$, and $v$ of $H$, such that $G-u$ and $H-v$ are LC-isomorphic?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure; I tried to find a counterexample but couldn't find one. But I also couldn't prove it (yet). Would that imply an effective enumeration?

Comment: If it is true, then you can make all the $n$-vertex LC-isomorphism classes by adding vertices to one member of each $(n-1)$-vertex LC-isomorphism class. Which can be fewer graphs to compare.  But it still isn't a super-fast generator.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a thought.

Based on https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(93)90357-Y I have tried to code a variant of LCIsomorphicGraphQ that is claimed to run in time $O(n^4)$. This seems simple (see their sec. 4 and Thm 4.1). Unfortunately the theorem as stated seems wrong: a simple counterexample for which their system of equations has no solutions but the graphs _are_ LC-isomorphic are the 3-cycle and the 3-path.

Comment: In case you want to check, here is the system of equations (same notation as in the paper):

$Y_3+Z_1=0\land X_1+Y_3=0\land T_3+X_1=0\land X_2+Y_3=0\land Y_3+Z_2=0\land T_3+X_2=0\land T_1+X_3+Y_2=0\land T_2+X_3+Y_1=0\land Y_1+Y_2+Z_3=0\land T_1 X_1+Y_1 Z_1=1\land T_2 X_2+Y_2 Z_2=1\land T_3 X_3+Y_3 Z_3=1$

Comment: Interestingly, this paper: quant-ph/0405023 gives the right result for the 3-cycle/path, but not for the 4-cycle/path. Hmmm.

Comment: I interpretted the paper of Bouchet as testing LC equivalence, not LC+isomorphism equivalence.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, I can confirm that; under isomorphisms their algorithm yields the correct result.

Ok, then my original question still stands though; enumerating, not checking equivalence.